# How to move button

Tags: html, css

[please can you check my image tha is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpebI.jpg) I have a problem moving my button to right upper corner

for some reasons it stick in left upper corner**

and when i start moving my button , all other element moves around**

```css
.ph-button {
    
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;    
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    font-family: "Gotham Rounded A","Gotham Rounded B",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;   
    padding: 9px 19px 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
   


}


/*Red
==========================*/
.ph-btn-red {

    background-color: #ED5A5A !important;
    border-color: #EA4343 !important;



}
.ph-btn-red:hover, .ph-btn-red:focus, .ph-btn-red:active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EB4848 !important;
    border-color: #E83131 !important;    

}
```

```html
<div class="ph-container">
  
    
     <div class="ph-float">
        <a href='#' class='ph-button ph-btn-red'>Ask Question</a>
    </div>    
</div>    

<div class="ph-clear"></div>
```

[this is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpebI.jpg)

Comment: There are heaps of ways to do this...but your padding css gives the padding left and padding right both 19px. Another way is to get rid of padding and just have margin-left or use bootstrap and use pull-right. There are heaps of other ways.

Comment: please can you check my image tha is attached

Answer (score 0):

```
.ph-container{
    text-align: right;
}
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ph-button {
    
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;    
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-style: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    font-family: "Gotham Rounded A","Gotham Rounded B",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;   
    padding: 9px 19px 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
   


}


/*Red
==========================*/
.ph-btn-red {

    background-color: #ED5A5A !important;
    border-color: #EA4343 !important;



}
.ph-btn-red:hover, .ph-btn-red:focus, .ph-btn-red:active {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EB4848 !important;
    border-color: #E83131 !important;    

}
```

```html
<div class="ph-container">
  
    
     <div class="ph-float">
        <a href='#' class='ph-button ph-btn-red'>Ask Question</a>
    </div>    
</div>    

<div class="ph-clear"></div>
```

Comment: this is helps. can you please check image that is attached to my question